# How can I safely commit a .git directory

Tags: git, .git-folder

I am working on a git-related software and I have included unit tests  in my code.

I have created a test git project (under a subdirectory) to be used by the tests: `resources/test-git-project`
This test git project is not associated to any remote, but it contains commits/tags/branches.

What is the safest way to commit the contents of `resources/test-git-project` in git?

Comment: Just to be clear: you had a git repo `resources/test-git-project` and you created a nested git repo inside under `.git` or what? Or you have created empty git repo and wander what is that `.git` directory inside your empty repository?

Comment: Still, I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to handle your repo, like committing changes? What do you mean by safest way?

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs I try to commit the contents of a test git repository (which is a subdir of my real repository), as plain files. I'm trying to find out how to commit `.git` directory, so that anyone that checks out the project can get it exactly as I committed it in order to perform the unit tests?

Comment: `.git` is the internal directory of a git repository and you should not touch it. Everything that is stored there is handled automatically. Either me understood the question incorrectly because of not clear question, or you're doing something totally wrong.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs this comes up if you need a git repo as a test asset, i.e. building a plugin that uses git, you need a know state git repo to operate on, and you need that asset committed to another repo. kind of a funky case, but it exists

Comment: @RalphCallaway That was exactly my use case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Thibault D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2003763/thibault-d) answer I found the solution I was looking for:

I have **renamed** `.git` to `gitdir` and it is now commitable:

When I want to perform updates or see the status of the test repo I do the following:

```
git --git-dir=resources/test-git-project/gitdir --work-tree=resources/test-git-project anycommand
```

Before performing the unit tests I copy the directory `resources/test-git-project` under `/tmp` and rename `/tmp/test-git-project/gitdir` to `/tmp/test-git-project/.git`, so that I don't have to mess with `--git-dir` option on my test code.

Answer (score 3):

You could either zip it or add it as a `git submodule`, depending on how often you want to change the contents and what parts of the `.git` folder are important for your tests.

Adding it as a submodule will make it easier to access the `.git` directory but will not really *commit* the content of the directory and manage revisions of it. You will even have different contents on different clones because of when you perform `git pull` (if you add/remove branches, if you rebase branches, if you locally create dangling objects, etc...)

You could also probably do something with [the --git-dir option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git---git-dirltpathgt) .

Comment: Zip seems a good idea, but I will wait for a while for a better one.

Answer (score -2):

You should not have nested git repositories.

Have one unique repo for the code and the test (kind of common), or have two separate repos, but at the same hierachical level in your filesystem, not nested on into another.

Comment: the "nested" git repo is just an asset used in testing in this case so it makes sense to check it into another git repo.